# Group by one Column in Sql Server and Order by Another Column not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by

i have table "ApplicationEventsSearch" with two column **Keyword and EventDate**
i want to have a query that return result as distinct keyword , but ordered  asc by EventDate
i have tried many combination , but none worked

Data

```
Keyword EventDate
123457  2020-09-01
123457fdfdfdfd  2020-09-01
123457fdfdfdfd  2020-09-02
123457fdfdfdfd  2020-09-03
```

Desired Result

```
1-123457fdfdfdfd,
2-123457
```

and what i have tried so far

```
SELECT 
       [Keyword],EventDate
  FROM [NavaarDb-Dev].[dbo].[ApplicationEventsSearch]
  group by Keyword,EventDate
 order by EventDate


SELECT 
      distinct [Keyword],EventDate
  FROM [NavaarDb-Dev].[dbo].[ApplicationEventsSearch]
  group by Keyword,EventDate
 order by EventDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you after just `MIN` or `MAX` in the `ORDER BY`?

```sql
SELECT Keyword
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY KeyWord
ORDER BY MAX(EventDate) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTEST;
go
select * INTO #tTEST from (values 
('123457', '2020-09-01'),
('123457fdfdfdfd', '2020-09-01'),
('123457fdfdfdfd', '2020-09-02'),
('123457fdfdfdfd', '2020-09-03')) V(Keyword, EventDate);
```

Query

```
;with kw_cte as (select *, row_number() over (partition by Keyword order by EventDate desc) rn from #tTEST)
select
  concat_ws('-', row_number() over (order by EventDate desc), Keyword) string
from kw_cte 
where rn=1;
```

Results

```
string
1-123457fdfdfdfd
2-123457
```